# Conditional Installing of softwares based on operating system

Tags: windows, batch-file, installation, software-distribution, cd

I have 32bit and 64bit softwares that we need to distribute using CD. What is the proper way by which user can automatically install the software based on his operating system. I had written a batch script (converted to exe) and attached to autorun.inf file. Batch script detects the operating system and installs the needed type of software.

Batch script shows up a popup console windows which I don't want. And if I compiled it to exe using online tools (tried multiple tools) to make it run in invisible mode, the compiled exe is being determined as malware threat.

Comment: If you have a batch file that works, what's your question?

Comment: sorry edit has been done. Is there any other proper way to do it

Comment: Use a setup tool like inno-setup?

Comment: You should use a proprietary installer solution which can determine the bitness of the PC and install the appropriate software. This site is for people looking for help to fix their programming issues; you actually need a software solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can run that command prompt in the non-interactive system space with psexec.  However, that will also not display the progress bars for the applications that you are installing.  The long-term solution to your problem is to use an application distribution system, such as Configuration Manager.  (not a CM shill, that's just one option)